# Can I Connect dashcam Blackvue DR900S on OBDII connector in Volvo XC70 2015?

Tags: obd-ii

Do I get 12V on OBDII pin 16 without ignition ON?

Comment: OBD is not a good way to power anything. What are you trying to accomplish, to keep your dashcam running all the time? You will run your battery down faster.

Comment: I am aware of running the battery down, but this will not be an issue on a short time (3-4 hours). My concern is about OBDII-pin 16 gives batterypower without ignition ON.

Comment: @GdD nah they have sleep and wake up mode on good ones. I leave mine powered all the time, no issue's. Its a great security camera for my van. I don't see nothing wrong with powering from OBD2, its usually the same fused line that is going to one of the cig lighter plugs anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a good idea - leave the OBD connectors for OBD. Instead, a simpler solution is to look for an add-a-circuit device in your local car spares store. Plug it into a known 12V supply in the cars cabin fusebox, and run the power lead to the dashcam.

This is a much quicker solution than trying to find switched 12V in the OBD connector, and is completely reversible if you want to remove the dashcam when you sell the car.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you get constant voltage from pin16 on a OBD2 even with out ignition on. It is a direct fused line in most cases and a lot of the times it is also the same fused line as the main cigarette lighter plug (many people use to plug in accessories).